# What does JS code $$ mean?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does $$ mean in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/384873/what-does-mean-in-javascript)

I just saw this piece of code.

```
var buttons = $$('.add-select-row');
```

What does that do? Is that Prototype?

Comment: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/

Comment: Did you check this before asking: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384873/what-does-mean-in-javascript

Comment: So if I get the doc right, it gets all elemts having the class add-select-row and saves them in the buttons array?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1463867/601179

Comment: It **could** be Protoype, but it could also be any other library or a custom function which accepts CSS selectors (like `$$ = jQuery.noConflict()`). `$$` is a valid Javascript variable name, so **it could be anything** (without given any context).

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's prototype, and one of the first things in the manual:

http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/

Comment: Could also be [MooTools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window:dollars) or of unknown origins

Comment: You cant for sure say it's Prototype, as out of context it could be any variable.

Comment: He tagged the question 'prototype' seems pretty obvious to me

Comment: @Evert - I agree that he is probably talking about the PrototypeJS function, but that tag is actually referring to the `prototype` in general. There is a separate PrototypeJS tag to refer to that library. Chances are the wrong tag was picked though, so I've retagged it.

Answer (score 1):

`$$` is a variable holding a function (variable names starting with `$` are valid in JS).

A few frameworks uses `$$` as a shortcut to select multiple elements using a CSS Selector

- [Mootools](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars)
- [Prototype](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar-dollar/)
- And more...

Answer (score 0):

maybe $$ is a no conflict variable of jquery, somewhere in your code you have:

```
var $$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what libraries are in use on that page. jQuery normally uses $, but so do some other libraries, so common practice is to manually tell the library to use something else instead if you have more than one in use that would otherwise conflict.

This looks like jQuery has been told to use $$ via jQuery.noConflict(), which may mean that $ is in use by Prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, seems that this is [prototype](http://prototypejs.org/) library.

[`$$`](http://prototypejs.org/api/utility/dollar-dollar) Takes an arbitrary number of CSS selectors

Answer (score 0):

Technically, it does whatever you want it to.

For example, it could be jQuery..

```
(function($$) {
    // code
})(jQuery);
```

e: Out of context, there is no definitive answer. You can't for sure say its prototype just because prototype uses dollar-dollar.